# What's the adjective for a routine/mindless task that doesn't improve your actual skills?

Tags: vocabulary

I remember there was a specific adjective for this but I forgot the word. I've tried throwing "brainless", "routine" etc. into an online thesaurus but nothing's leading me back to the word anymore. It's so frustrating!

Anyone has a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: _Busywork_ is a common noun for it. Can't think of an adjective, unless it's _useless._

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "grunt", such as in the phrase *grunt work*.

One of the definitions applicable for grunt:

> one who does routine unglamorous work —often used attributively (grunt work)

Answer (score 2):

rote ~ a habitual or mechanical routine or procedure

Answer (score 1):

you can usually call them Mundane tasks.

Comment: [Why?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @choster, I don't understand the complaint.  The answer to why is because that's what the word means.  It's not like explaining a grammatical concept.

Comment: @Henry74 If the answer to why is because that's what the word means, the answer should explain that and provide a definition, with a suitable reference (e.g. a link to an online dictionary). The link goes to guidelines for writing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

From gaming, *grindy*. Back to the grind!

Answer (score 0):

Trivial. Or tedious, as in mindless tedium.